# UnauthorizedAccessException vs SecurityException

Tags: .net, exception, securityexception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

The MSDN constructor for a FileStream says that it may throw either an UnauthorizedAccessException or a SecurityException. Here's what MSDN says about these exceptions.

[UnauthorizedAccessException:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)
The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

[SecurityException:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception.aspx)
The exception that is thrown when a security error is detected.

How are these two similar exceptions different? What situations will trigger either of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown when there is a permissions error accessing the file on disk.  That is an error at the operating system level such as a normal user trying to overwrite an operating system file (like kernel32.dll).

A `SecurityException` is thrown if there is a security violation at the CLR level.  For example if you are running as a low access ClickOnce application and attempt to read / write to a place in the file system forbidden by the CLR security settings in the process.

Comment: So if I tried to write/create a file on a network drive which the current user does not have write access to then it would throw a UnauthorizedAccessException?

Comment: Please add some more description or example to understand how they actually differ?

Comment: `SecurityException` is thrown by some in-box APIs like `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey` (which also throws `UnauthorizedAccessException`, confusingly).